# SWF file is built with <debug>true</debug> but Debug menuitem in flash player is gray

Tags: flash, debugging, intellij-idea

The problem is explained in subject. I have debug version of Flash player. I build it with intellij idea. I want to debug it, but i can not. It doesnt connect to IDEA and the menu item is grey. Help me someone. Tested everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug of Debug Flash Player for Chrome. It wouldn't let you debug swf, delivered from web. Only from file system...

Answer (score 0):

Is [this](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-93759) yours? Let's continue discussion in YouTrack.